# Oauth2 Password Grant type in Express-Gateway

Tags: express-gateway

We are trying to implement the "Password" grant type through Express-Gateway in our Microservices. But we could not find any documentation on the Express-Gateway and the global endpoint "/oauth2/token" gives an "unauthorised" error when we try to access it through postman.

Any reference document or suggestions here will be appreciated.

Let me know if any informaton is required.

Amit

Answer (score 0):

Try basic auth with user's login and secret from oauth credentials, and pass json in body:

```
{
  "grant_type": "password",
  "username": "<login>",
  "password": "<password>"
}
```